# I can't open the activity because of a layout issue

Tags: java, android, xml

I am having trouble with the layout. Something is wrong that when I click the button it is not opening the activity for it. Please help me solve this issue. I am running a mediaplayer on Android. This is the main page XML. This happens only in the android version 14. All of the other activities open without any problems but this one doesn't.

I have tried different configurations but I couldn't resolve the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/pic3">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nowplayingbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:text="@string/playing_top"
    android:textColor="@color/mintgreen"
    android:layout_below="@id/adView"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:gravity="center"

    />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/track_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/nowplayingbar"

       />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@color/lightgray"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/progressedTime"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.03"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/_0_00_"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"

            />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBarMedia"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.84"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.03"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"

            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:text="@string/_0_00"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/repeatOn"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_repeaton"
            android:background="#0000FF"

            android:layout_width="25dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/repeaton" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/repeatOff"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_repeatoff"
            android:background="#F4A460"

            android:layout_width="25dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/repeatoff" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/samplebannerunitid"
        tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

in my main menu activity: this is the button to get into mainactivity and it isn't working...

```
       button1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                save_id(button1.getId());
                mInterstitialAd.show(mainpageactivity.this);
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(mainpageactivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(i);
            }

        });
```

Comment: First, what's button you click? and which way you implement open activity action?

Comment: `      button1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                save_id(button1.getId());
                mInterstitialAd.show(mainpageactivity.this);
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(mainpageactivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(i);
            }

        });`

this one to get from mainpageactivity to mainactivity. the other buttons work but i can't get into mainactivity.

Comment: first, check button1 findViewById with what ID in xml. seconds, you can use Log inside setOnClickListener to check if else and see result, to make sure click event go to else block